# Clean and Rebuild a Package with Packrat alongside in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, devtools, roxygen2, packrat

Coming from a python playground and being a big fan of `virtualenv` and ofcourse, a rookie in R, I intended to have a similar setup in my R projects and packages with the aid of `packrat`. (At least it seemed intuitive.)

So far, without `packrat`, I would run `"Clean and Rebuild"` on my package in RStudio and things worked as expected.

But now I have `packrat` installed and initialized on the project, which in turn, routes all the subsequent installs to the `lib` folder in the `/packrat` dir. This again is working as expected.

Now the issue is with rebuilding my package (which is btw, installed into the `packrat` by means of `packrat::install()` ) 
Every time I run `"Clean and Rebuild"` I get the following error in the `Build` window of RStudio:

```
==> roxygen2::roxygenize('.', roclets = c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))

Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘roxygen2’
Calls: suppressPackageStartupMessages ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

In reality, I have `devtools`, `roxygen2` and other packages (including my own) installed with `packrat`.

What Am I missing?

Comment: In general, the need for virtualenv is less in R than in Python, because you basically only have one implementation. Mostly, stuff "just works". I do a lot of package dev, and I've never really felt the need for multiple environments.